# Is there any way to create class which extends from Canvas in Android?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, android-canvas

I'm trying to create a class that inherits Canvas class of Android. My reason is adding more robust and useful methods to that class for my game framework. When I tried to cast my AdvancedCanvas object to Canvas in `onDraw()` method. I do the drawing part in `draw()` method which takes an advancedcanvas object as a parameter. It causes an exception;

***java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas cannot be cast to com.example.x.AdvancedCanvas***

Here is my code block below

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        AdvancedCanvas advancedcanvas =  (AdvancedCanvas) canvas;
        draw(advancedcanvas);
    }
```

My real question is, is there any way to achieve that goal in the first place? Or any alternative ideas would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot make cast like that. Since onDraw is and override method, it gets parameter from somewhere else above, which is a canvas.
2. You can wrap that canvas object.
   make your `AdvancedCanvas` accept canvas as a parameter and hold ref to it inside, and add additional field and methods inside 'AdvancedCanvas'.

ex:

```
class AdvancedCanvas{
  private Canvas mCanvas;

  public AdvancedCanvas(Canvas canvas){ mCanvas = canvas }

  public void doSmt(){ //use mCanvas}
}
```

So you will be able to do:

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas){
 AdvancedCanvas ac = AdvancedCanvas(canvas);
}
```

Comment: I did the exact thing when I could not achieve my goal. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, `Canvas` is a parent class, `AdvancedCanvas` is a child class. Upcasting from child to parent is always allowed, but downcasting from parent to child involves a type check and can throw a ClassCastException.

for example:

```
Animal animal = getAnimal(); // Maybe a Dog? Maybe a Cat? Maybe an Animal?
if (animal instanceof Dog) { // only successful in this condition
    Dog castedDog = (Dog) animal;
}
```

But `Canvas` is not an instance of `AdvancedCanvas` , so error occured.

You could create a custom view if you like, [this is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122177/how-to-use-canvas-of-view-extended-class-into-activity-class)

**Edited**:
Try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        AdvancedCanvas advancedcanvas =  new AdvancedCanvas();

        advancedcanvas.property1 = canvas.property1;//prepare advancedcanvas 
        advancedcanvas.setProperty2(canvas.property2)//or like this

        draw(advancedcanvas);//then use advancedcanvas 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But is there any way to achieve it with a different approach. Because I would like to get my clients to use AdvancedCanvas type as a parameter in draw() method.

Comment: It is a good idea but unfortunately, there is no property that I can use in my class. Even Canvas class extends from BaseCanvas which have native methods from C++. I think this is an end of the story for my adventure :/ . But thanks anyway for trying.